How are ES6 module imports with HTTP redirects supposed to work?
When importing a JS module (e.g. https://example.com/module.js) from a URL that returns a 301/302 redirect to a specific version of the module (e.g. https://example.com/module-42.js), the redirected module is initiated as a separate instance.
This means that when explicitly importing the module from both the initial URL and the versioned URL, two instances of the module are created:
import "https://example.com/module.js"; // -> redirects to https://example.com/module-42.js
import "https://example.com/module-42.js";

Nevertheless, the value of import.meta.url inside the module is "https://example.com/module-42.js" in both cases:
// https://example.com/module-42.js
console.log(import.meta.url)

This behavior is the same in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safarie), but in Deno, the redirected URL and the versioned URL both point to the same module instance and only initialize the module once.
Imo, the way Deno handles redirects makes more sense because the redirect does not just point to the same module, it points to the identical resource which should not be treated as a separate module instance.
Reproducible example (the repo for this example can be found at https://github.com/unyt-org/redirect-example)


(async () =>
  console.log(
    (await import("https://redirect-example.unyt.app/module")).default == 
    (await import("https://redirect-example.unyt.app/module@version")).default
  )
)()



This evaluates to false when executed in a browser environment, but evaluates to true when executed in Deno.
This is a big problem when the modules have side effects during module initialization, since all side effects are executed twice.
Another scenario for which this is a big issue is when a redirected module (https://example.com/moduleA.js -> https://example.com/version1/moduleA.js) has a relative import to ./moduleB.js, which resolves correctly to https://example.com/version1/moduleB.js.
But if we are not importing https://example.com/moduleA.js and https://example.com/moduleB.js (which gets resolved to https://example.com/version1/moduleB.js) from our root module, we get one instantiation of the redirected https://example.com/version1/moduleA.js, but two instantiations of moduleB: One instantiation through the root module import, and a different instantiation through the relative import from moduleA - the two modules are not treated as the same module!
Is this intended behavior (is there a specification for this somewhere since this is not part of the ECMAScript spec) and is there any way to get around this problem?

im guessing its up to the runtime to decide how to handle modules.

Indeed, the spec for the module import semantics is intentionally vague. Out of curiosity, what is the situation that causes an incoming URL for a static resource to respond directly once and then with a redirect subsequently? I can imagine good arguments for either behavior, as to me the bottom line would be a server anomaly.

And how is the browser supposed to know that the two URLs represent identical resources?

Specifier resolution is the responsibility of each runtime and AFAIK is not governed by any external specification. Are you importing modules specifically for side effects? Can you [edit] the question to clarify: How is this a "problem"? You can verify that both of the example URLs redirect to the same one: console.log(new Set(await Promise.all(["https://esm.sh/canvas-confetti", "https://esm.sh/canvas-confetti@1.9.3"].map(async (url) => (await fetch(url)).url))).size === 1); //=> true

@Pointy Two URLs represent the identical resource when they are identical URLs. We are talking about a redirect to the same URL here.

@benS well I still think there's an argument to be made that interpreting two different URLs mentioned in import statements (in the source) should be treated as two different modules, under the presumption that the author of the code would expect a different URL to load a different module. I'm not saying I think that's necessarily the best answer, but it doesn't seem like the worst answer.

@Pointy okay I see your point, but then again the import.meta.url is the same for both modules, which is a bit contradicting

@benS I agree that it's a worthy question and I am very interested in an authoritative answer.

Context

How are ES6 module imports with HTTP redirects supposed to work?

Before getting to an answer… I interpret the question to be asking how:

import specifiers which are also valid URLs
that cause network requests to be made which result in responses that are categorized as URL redirection
will resolve to specific module data, and whether multiple redirections to the same resource will result in multiple evaluations of the same module code

Answer
Before anything else: you were correct when you said:

…this is not part of the ECMAScript spec…

Module specifiers are indeed simply opaque strings — a given runtime can resolve specifiers however it is programmed to do so.
Some specifiers might resemble URLs, and a runtime might or might not resolve the specifier by making a network request. Or the runtime might implement its own internal specifier mappings… or it might implement a caching layer… or any other number of intermediate steps between parsing the specifier string and resolving module data. The spec doesn't prescribe how this should happen, which allows for flexibility.
There are no committed alignments across runtimes in regard to the way that URL-like specifiers should be resolved to module data (or whether those modules should be evaluated more than once), and — as you observed — they aren't implemented in the same way. The network layer itself in each runtime can also be implemented in an arbitrary way.
For these reasons, there are no guarantees of conformity beyond what each runtime provides for itself. You'll have to discover and verify claims for yourself.

Toward helping you test various runtimes
Below, I will provide some code that you can use to test various runtimes/browsers. It was created and tested using Deno v1.45.3, but you should be able to adapt the code in the server module to other JS runtimes — I used only ECMA and WHATWG APIs (nothing Deno-specific):
.env:
HOSTNAME=localhost
PORT=8000


deno.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "lib": ["deno.window"]
  },
  "imports": {
    "@std/assert": "jsr:@std/assert@^1.0.0"
  },
  "tasks": {
    "serve": "deno run --no-prompt --env --allow-env=HOSTNAME,PORT --allow-net=localhost:8000 serve.ts",
    "test": "deno test --no-prompt --env --allow-env=HOSTNAME,PORT --allow-net=localhost:8000 server.test.ts"
  }
}


env.ts:
import { assert } from "@std/assert/assert";

export function getPartialEnv<const T extends string>(
  keys: Iterable<T>,
): Record<T, string> {
  const env = {} as Record<T, string>;
  for (const k of keys) {
    const v = Deno.env.get(k);
    assert(v, `Environment variable not found for "${k}"`);
    env[k] = v;
  }
  return env;
}

export default getPartialEnv(["HOSTNAME", "PORT"]);


serve.ts:
import env from "./env.ts";

import { handleRequest } from "./server.ts";

await using server = Deno.serve({
  handler: handleRequest,
  hostname: env.HOSTNAME,
  port: Number(env.PORT),
});

await server.finished;


server.test.ts:
import { assertEquals } from "@std/assert/equals";
import { assertStrictEquals } from "@std/assert/strict-equals";

import env from "./env.ts";

import { handleRequest, pathPrefix } from "./server.ts";

Deno.test("server", async (ctx) => {
  const {
    promise: serverStarted,
    resolve: resolveServerStarted,
  } = Promise.withResolvers<void>();

  await using server = Deno.serve({
    handler: handleRequest,
    hostname: env.HOSTNAME,
    onListen: () => resolveServerStarted(),
    port: Number(env.PORT),
  });

  await ctx.step("starts", () => serverStarted);

  await ctx.step("responds with side-effect modules", async () => {
    const specifier =
      new URL(`http://${env.HOSTNAME}:${env.PORT}${pathPrefix}/b.js`).href;
    await import(specifier);
  });

  await ctx.step("expected modules are evaluated only once", async (ctx) => {
    const countsActual = (globalThis as typeof globalThis & {
      _counts: Partial<Record<string, number>>;
    })._counts;

    const countsExpected: Partial<Record<string, number>> = {};

    const fileNames = ["a.js", "b.js"];

    for (const fileName of fileNames) {
      const key =
        new URL(`http://${env.HOSTNAME}:${env.PORT}${pathPrefix}/${fileName}`)
          .href;
      countsExpected[key] = 1;
      await ctx.step(
        `${JSON.stringify(fileName)}`,
        () => assertStrictEquals(countsActual[key], 1),
      );
    }

    await ctx.step(
      "no additional modules evaluated",
      () => assertEquals(countsActual, countsExpected),
    );
    // console.log(countsActual);
  });

  await ctx.step("stops", async () => {
    await Promise.all([server.shutdown(), server.finished]);
  });
});


server.ts:
// URL path prefix for module cache isolation
export const pathPrefix = "/so-78785224";

// increment a global count each time a module is evaluated
const incrementEvalCount = `const counts = (globalThis._counts ??= {});
counts[import.meta.url] = (counts[import.meta.url] ?? 0) + 1;`;

const indexHtml = `<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Module evalutaion test - Stack Overflow Question ID 78785224</title>
    <script type="module">
        import "${pathPrefix}/b.js";
        console.log("module evaluation counts:", globalThis._counts);
    </script>
</head>
<body>See dev tools</body>
</html>`;

function createTextResponse(text: string, contentType: string): Response {
  const bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(text);
  return new Response(bytes, {
    headers: new Headers([
      ["Content-Length", bytes.byteLength.toString()],
      ["Content-Type", contentType],
    ]),
  });
}

export function handleRequest(request: Request): Response {
  const url = new URL(request.url);

  if (url.pathname === "/") return createTextResponse(indexHtml, "text/html");

  if (url.pathname.startsWith(pathPrefix)) {
    switch (url.pathname.slice(pathPrefix.length)) {
      case "/a.js": {
        const moduleText = `${incrementEvalCount}\nexport default "a"\n`;
        return createTextResponse(moduleText, "text/javascript");
      }
      case "/a2.js": {
        // redirect
        return new Response(null, {
          headers: new Headers([
            ["Location", new URL("./a.js", url.href).href],
          ]),
          status: 301,
        });
      }
      case "/b.js": {
        const moduleText =
          `import "./a.js";\nimport "./a2.js";\n${incrementEvalCount}\nexport default "b"\n`;
        return createTextResponse(moduleText, "text/javascript");
      }
    }
  }
  return new Response("Not found", { status: 404 });
}

export default { fetch: handleRequest };


You can run the server with the following command in order to test various runtimes:
deno task serve

…or test with Deno directly using
deno task test


thanks for your extensive answer, we also already have a setup to test this behavior in different runtimes (https://github.com/unyt-org/redirect-example) but this still doesn't really solve the problem :)

There is no standard for this, so all that we can do in order to determine the behavior is to infer it either from experiment, reading the source-code or documentation of different browsers, which is not a reliable manner to determine behavior, it could have different results in different browsers and it may change in newer versions.
There is a good argument, as pointed out by Pointy in a comment for different URLs being interpreted as different resources and, quite frankly, it's difficult to see why someone would want to import the same lib in two different versions.
You can work-around this though in multiple manners. For example you could do something like this:
function importResource(url) {
    let resource = cache.get(url);
    if (!resource) {
        resource = (await import(url));
        cache.put(url, resource);
    }
    return resource;
}

of course, you will need to make sure cache has a proper type, at least having a get and a put method, the get method resolving whether a certain URL is already loaded. Here you will need to compare the url-to-be-loaded with the already cached URLs and determine whether the current one was already imported. Of course, we could implement this comparison like we want and we could say that a versioned URL is the same as a similar URL in a similar version or even without the version.
Another possibility is to generate a specific id for the page that represents your page load in a unique manner and have a server-side end point that acts as a proxy to other resources and maps the page id to the resources it already loaded and then import into your page resources by that proxy and resolve resource duplication issues inside that proxy.

of course you can create a custom import function, but this is only possible with dynamic imports. A server side solution doesn't fix the problem either if we just have a CDN that provides JS modules. The problem is not that there aren't any workarounds for this issue in specific scenarios - this more of a fundamental discussion on how runtimes handle or should handle the standard ES imports.

@benS you could have the server-side proxy receive the cdn and decide what to do. I understood the discussion of course and the first part of my answer was stating that there is no standard for this. I did not delve into the "should" as you suggested, as it would have been an opinionated answer. But, instead I described work-arounds to cope with several scenarios. Nevertheless, thanks for the comment accompanying the down-vote.
